# How can I remove an item from a cell's validation list when the cell already contains a value on that list?

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I would like to remove an item from a cell's validation list when the cell already contains an item that has been selected from that validation list, in order to prevent the same item being re-selected in that cell.

Suppose an empty cell has the validation list {10,20,30,40,50}. When I select, say, '20' and then go back into that cell's validation list, I want to just see {10,30,40,50}. If I then select, say, '40' and go back into the validation list again, I want to see {10,20,30,50}, etc. It's important this also works for text values.

I originally viewed this problem as being about creating 2 lists and joining them together; e.g. in my first example, removing '20' can be thought of as creating lists {10} and {30,40,50}, so I tried using the 'comma' operator to join two ranges in the Data Validation dialogue, without success. I tried the same approach in a named formula and using that in the DV dialogue. Same result.

I created a UDF:

```
Function UNION(rRng1 As Range, rRng2 As Range) As Range
    Dim rRng12 As Range
    Set rRng12 = Union(rRng1, rRng2)
    UNION = rRng12
End Function
```

and tried this in both the DV dialogue and via a named range. Still didn't work.

[EDIT]: This functionality needs to work in a structured table, where one of the columns is updated from the validation list.

I've concluded that I need to use an array formula within a named range, and reference this from the DV dialogue, but I'm not clear on how this can be done?

Comment: I believe the solution to this is for the list to be dynamically calculated every time it is accessed, for which the validation list would need to be an array formula, with no helper cells allowed. Is there a way to use an array formula as the source for a validation list, perhaps via a named range?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. It will work for numbers, but will probably need some work if your list is text.

In E1:E5, put your list (10,20,30,40,50). In G1:G5, put the formula

```
{=SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$5*($E$1:$E$5<>$A$1),$E$1:$E$5,""),ROW())}
```

That takes the list from E, removes the number in A1 that matches, and sorts it. Now create a named range called `dvExclude` with this as the RefersTo

=Sheet1!$G$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$G$1:$G$5,COUNT(Sheet1!$G$1:$G$5))

The G range will have errors at the bottom and this will exclude those - `COUNT` only counts numbers, not errors.

Finally, set up your data validation in A1 as List and =dvExclude.

[image: data validation excluding selected value]

Comment: Hi Dick, thanks for this, but I've realised from your suggestion that I missed out a crucial requirement, which I've included as an EDIT. Your solution is feasible for one cell with validation, but not for an unknown number in a Table. :(

Comment: Hi Dick, Deb Dalgliesh has a tutorial on this. See my answer.

Comment: Hi teylyn, do you have a link to that tutorial?